# Running a specific Windows application on a Mac

Tags: windows, mac

I am interested in running a single Windows program on my Macbook. I have looked at various options, including bootcamp, however since it is only a single program, I was looking for a way to minimize the amount of storage used. I also had the same problem while looking at virtual machines. The program is a tutor.com classroom that is an online tutoring application. It is an .msi file. I have tried seeing if this program is compatible with Wine, but it is not. I am not too familiar with any of these methods. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**USB Flash Drive** [Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LLEODCK)

If space is an issue, you could install a VM on a flash drive plugged into a USB port. I've run VMs this way in the past, and it also makes your VM completely portable. This will give you the **best compatibility** as your app will be running on native Windows. For Windows you'll probably want at least a 32GB drive or more as [Windows 10 requires a minimum of 20GB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs) for 64 bit install. You can get one on Amazon for less than $20 ([Amazon 64GB USB 3.0 Flash Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LLEODCK)).

I think this is going to be the easiest solution for you, given that the tutor.com app is probably not going to be officially supported with one of the compatability layer solutions below.

---

**WineBottler** [Link](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) | [Compatible App Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/)

Free solution that provides a GUI interface for running and installing apps with Wine.

> No need to install emulators, virtualizers or boot into other operating systems – WineBottler runs your Windows-based programs directly on your Mac.
>   This is possible thanks to a Windows-compatible subsystem, which is provided by the great OpenSource tool Wine.

---

**CrossOver** [Link](https://www.codeweavers.com/) | [Compatible App Database](https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility)

Commercial solution that with customer support. Also has a large database of apps that you can search to check if your app is compatible with CrossOver

> El Capitan compatible CrossOver Mac 15 is the easiest way to run Microsoft Windows software on your Mac without buying a Windows license, rebooting or using a virtual machine. CrossOver Mac makes it easy to launch Windows programs natively from the dock, and integrates Mac OS functionality like cross-platform copy & paste and shared file systems to your Windows applications.